# How to turn data downloaded from JQuery.get, into ArrayBuffer?

Tags: jquery, webgl, dataview, texture2d, arraybuffer

I have attempted to find an answer to this for the past three days with various keywords I know of, but could not get far. I am new to JavaScript/WebGL so this could potentially turn out to be a complete ignorance on my part, please forgive me if that's the case.

This is what I do to download a binary file (a custom image file format) from my server, and reading the first four bytes (Int32) out of the downloaded data:

```
TileImage.prototype.LoadFromUrl = function (imageUrl) {
    $.get(imageUrl, function (imageData) {
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(imageData); // Verified 'imageData' is good.
        var view = new DataView(buffer);         // Create a data view on buffer.
        var dwordValue = view.getInt32(0);       // Read the first four bytes.
        alert("The first Uint32 value is " + dwordValue);
    });
}
```

The downloaded data 'imageData' is of the correct size (imageData.length) as the file on server, so I presume the download is successful.

I intend to read into the downloaded file, and extract header information (and use the rest of image data in WebGL Texture2D for display). So the question is then: is that the way to deal with downloaded custom images (for use as textures in WebGL)? If not, then what would your recommendations be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it with a plain ol' XHR:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-reponseTypeArrayBuffer

You need to set the responseType property of the xhr object to 'arraybuffer'.

If your image data is uncompressed RGBA, it should be usable in WebGL as-is. If it's compressed, you need to put it in an image first. See the Blob API for how to create an object URL and use that as image src.

```
var blob = new BlobBuilder().append(arraybuffer).getBlob();
img.onload = function() { window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src); };
img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my day job does not spare me much time. Thanks for the tips, Ilmari, they helped a lot! The unfortunate thing is it does not work on my latest Firefox (and of course IE 9, but that doesn't worry me too much). I am still trying to figure out a way for it to work in Firefox 5.0 (because jQuery.get works), so please do give me a pointer if there is anything else I need to know. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi @Ilmari, it seems like Firefox 6.0 Beta does support it! Good news there, they currently have not implemented Uint8Array and DataView for me to read into the buffer, but Int8Array is there for me to use at least :)

Comment: My apology, Uint8Array is supported, I mis-typed it as UInt8Array!